# Multiple definitions and First defined error

Tags: c, makefile, multiple-definition-error, ansi-c

I have written a small C program which is assembled of several files.
When I compile, I get an error for "multiple definitions".

My main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "general_structs.h"

#define FOREVER for(;;)
#define INPUT_LEN 30

int main()
{
    char command[INPUT_LEN];
    char *func;
    int i;
    int t;

    FOREVER
    {
        if(scanf("%s", command) == 1)
        {
            func = strtok(command, " ");
            for(i=0;cmd[i].func != NULL;i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(func, cmd[i].name) == 0)
                {
                    (*((cmd[i].func)));
                    t = 1;
                }
            }
            if(t == 1)
            {
                printf("No such command");
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;   
}
```

My mat.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "general_structs.h"

#define LENGTH 100
#define SIXTEEN 16
#define SIZE 4


void read_mat()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char tmp_name[LENGTH];
    char num_buffer[LENGTH];
    char *token;
    double num_list[16];
    double tmp_num = 0;

    scanf("%[^,], %s", tmp_name, num_buffer);

    token = strtok(num_buffer, ",");

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(token, "0") == 0)
        {
            num_list[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp_num = atof(token);
            if(tmp_num == 0)        
            {
                printf("Error in parameter: %d\n", (i-1));
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                num_list[i] = tmp_num;
            }
        }   
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    if(!strcmp(tmp_name, "MAT_A"))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                mats[0].mat[0][i][j] = num_list[k];
                k++;
            }

    }
    else if(!strcmp(tmp_name, "MAT_B"))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                mats[1].mat[0][i][j] = num_list[k];
                k++;
            }
    }
    else if(!strcmp(tmp_name, "MAT_C"))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                mats[2].mat[0][i][j] = num_list[k];
                k++;
            }
    }
    else if(!strcmp(tmp_name, "MAT_D"))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                mats[3].mat[0][i][j] = num_list[k];
                k++;
            }
    }
    else if(!strcmp(tmp_name, "MAT_E"))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                mats[4].mat[0][i][j] = num_list[k];
                k++;
            }
    }
    else if(!strcmp(tmp_name, "MAT_F"))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
             for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
             {
                mats[5].mat[0][i][j] = num_list[k];
                k++;
             }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No such matrix name.");
    }
}
```

My general_structs.h file:

```
#define SIZE 4
#define SIZE_NAME 5
#define SIZE_FUNC 10

typedef double matrix[SIZE][SIZE];

matrix MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F;

void read_mat(void);

struct 
{
    char name[SIZE_NAME];
    matrix *mat;
} mats[] = {
        {"MAT_A", &MAT_A},
        {"MAT_B", &MAT_B},
        {"MAT_C", &MAT_C},
        {"MAT_D", &MAT_D},
        {"MAT_E", &MAT_E},
        {"MAT_F", &MAT_F},
        {"non", NULL}
      };

struct
{
    char name[SIZE_FUNC];
    void (*func)(void);
} cmd[] = {
        {"read_mat", read_mat},
        {"not_valid", NULL}
      };
```

My make file:

```
int_loop: my_math.o int_loop.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic my_math.o int_loop.o -o int_loop

int_loop.o : int_loop.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic int_loop.c -o int_loop.o

my_math.o : my_math.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic my_math.c -o my_math.o
```

I have been trying to solve this issue with various techniques but yet with no success.

The error I recieve is:

```
gcc -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.o mat.o -o mamantest
mat.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `mats'
main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
mat.o:(.data+0x70): multiple definition of `cmd'
main.o:(.data+0x70): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mamantest] Error 1
```

Why does this error occurs? How do I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the header file you *define* the variables `mats` and `cmd`, meaning both [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (both source files that includes the header file) will have those defined.

The variables should be defined only in a single place, in a single source file, like

```
struct mat mats[7] = { ... };
```

The above *defines* the array `mats`, and like I said should be done in only one place.

For the other source file you *declare* the variables, which can be done in the header file like e.g.

```
extern struct mat
{
    ...
} mats[7];
```

The above *declare* the variable `mats` as an array of seven `mat` structures. It also define the *structure* so it can be used to e.g. define the array.

---

After modifications suggested above, the complete header file should look something like

```
// First header include guards (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)
#ifndef GENERIC_STRUCTS_H
#define GENERIC_STRUCTS_H

#define SIZE 4
#define SIZE_NAME 5
#define SIZE_FUNC 10

typedef double matrix[SIZE][SIZE];

// Declare the variables (note the added use of the extern keyword)
extern matrix MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F;

void read_mat(void);

// Define a structure named mat (note added structure tag name)
struct mat
{
    char name[SIZE_NAME];
    matrix *mat;
};

// Define a structure named command (note added structure tag name)
struct command
{
    char name[SIZE_FUNC];
    void (*func)(void);
};

// Now declare variables of the previous structures
extern struct mat mats[7];
extern struct command cmd[2];

// End of header include guard
#endif
```

That header file only declares variables, and can be included in all your source files.

Then in a *single* source file (for example your `main.c` file) you do the actual variable definitions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "general_structs.h"

matrix MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F;

struct mat mats[7] = {
    {"MAT_A", &MAT_A},
    {"MAT_B", &MAT_B},
    {"MAT_C", &MAT_C},
    {"MAT_D", &MAT_D},
    {"MAT_E", &MAT_E},
    {"MAT_F", &MAT_F},
    {"non", NULL}
};

struct command cmd[2] = {
    {"read_mat", read_mat},
    {"not_valid", NULL}
};

#define FOREVER for(;;)
#define INPUT_LEN 30

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

The important thing you need to learn here is that there is a difference between *declaring* and *defining* something.

A declaration is basically telling the compiler that "this thing exists somewhere", and a definition is telling the compiler "this *is* the thing".

The problem is that unless a thing has already been declared, a definition is also a declaration, and many simply call these combined definitions/declarations just declaration, which muddles the whole concept up a bit.

Comment: If I do that I won't have a "$.h" file (general_structs.h). As it is part of the task to have one..

Comment: @JinKazama You still need the header file for the *structure* definitions, the `matrix` type alias, and the *declarations* of the variables. You just need to move the *definitions* of those variables into a single source file. Updated my answer with a modified header file.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your very infromative answer. if the "defining" part of the struct should only be in a single source file (for example, "main.c"), then the other file ("mat.c") won't know these structs. Thats why I assumed that they should be in a header, where all sources can approach and read. Isnt it correct?

Comment: @JinKazama Defining a structure and defining a variable are two different things. A structure definition is a compiler-only thing, once the compiler has the structure definition it's not needed anymore, and it's not save into the object files. Variable definitions, on the other hand, *are* stored in the object files. That's why defining a variable in a header file can lead to multiple definition errors, because it will be defined in two or more object files. So like in my example, the definition of the actual structure can be in the header file, but not the definition of the variables.

Comment: Thanks again for your fast and informative answer. So if I define the variables in 1 source file, "main.c", the other source file "mat.c" will know these variables if I call them?

Comment: @JinKazama Yes if they are *declared* in that source file, for example by having the declarations in the header file as I shown.

Comment: I just did exactly what you offered and compiled. I put your "defining" structs block in my "main.c". I get a huge error output. don't think it's the right way.